# Rename tag [fileset] -> [filesets]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I believe I just created the tag `fileset` when editing tags for [How to add several files to a fileset at once with a regular expression?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/32981) and then realised that `filesets` seemed more appropriate (the library is filesets.el), but I can't rename the tag myself.

Answer (score 2):

I agree, we usually use the plural for countable nouns. So I've renamed the tag.